# Query to find phone number based on combination of other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Query to select all phone number from combination of `circle`, `subscriber Type`, `subscriber sub type`, `Device Type` with `RES` status as “Y”.

select combination of `circle`, `subscriber Type`, `subscriber sub type`, `Device Type` with `RES` status as “Y” 
Suppose a table contain data as shown 
[image: datea]

It is just a sample

How can I find all the phone number in different combination of other column
as `Subscriber type`, `Subscriber Sub type`, `Device Type`, `RES` (Prepaid,Consumer,Mobile ,y)?

Comment: There is one row with `Prepaid, Consumer, Mobile ,y`. So you want the query to show all other four rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can write a simple `SELECT` query to get these, e.g.:

```
SELECT phone_number subscriber_type, subscriber_sub_type, device_type
FROM table
WHERE res = 'y';
```